# how to add image to invoice print layout

Tags: acumatica

I have invoice print layout designed using the advanced layout designer. I can add the branch logo. But I cannot add any other picture , say I have a static image that should come in all invoices. I cannot see an option to browse my PC folders and select an image in advance layout designer

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link is available from the report properties rather than field properties